# Sublime Text Multilingual Unicode Rendering

Tags: font, language, text-editor, unicode, sublimetext

I've been using Sublime Text for years and noticed that the rendering of Devanagari unicode characters doesn't work. Has anyone figured a way to make this work? I haven't noticed any problem rendering other unicode characters, examples below. Devanagari script is used by > 600 million users, so surely this is important, but I wonder why it has not received any attention.

Correctly rendered examples:

`ä é è ß æ`

`我家是这样的. 这是一个出口. 绿茶`

Incorrectly rendered examples:
[image]. This should have been `प्रकास स्वास्थ्य`

Sublime Text Build 4126 (Stable Channel), Mac OS 11.3.1.

Comment: Does it only happen in Sublime or also in TextEdit or Mail?

Comment: TextEdit, Mail, MS Word all render these characters correctly.

Comment: If this is s Sublime specific issue, did you bring it to the attention of the developers? What was there reaction?

Comment: @nohillside I haven't, but it seems others have (see https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/why-unicode-font-rendering-wont-fix/21978, https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/unicode-reading/257, https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/unicode-compound-letters-do-not-display-correctly/6358, and https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/myanmar-unicode-font-problem/4885). I find it weird that such an important issue has been ignored for so long.

Comment: I might agree, but asking this here won‘t speed up things.

Comment: @nohillside I understand. I asked to see if someone here knows of a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think that neither Sublime Text nor BBEdit have any support for RTL scripts like Arabic/Hebrew or the various complex Indic scripts like Devanagari that require reordering and glyph substitution.  Only the developers can answer why not.

There may be an add-on for Arabic [here](https://github.com/praveenvijayan/Sublime-Text-2-BIDI).

Comment: @MattDMo  Do you have a reference, or the special settings required?  It doesn't do Arabic for me by default.

Comment: @MattDMo Also I can't find any mention of adding such support in the documentation or the support site, e.g. https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/arabic-and-unicode-typing/41561/22

Comment: apparently I was mistaken. I saw some discussion of it on the Sublime Discord server at some point, and thought it had been implemented, but apparently it hasn't, as it would involve significant rework of the internals. It is the number one most requested feature on Github, however. +1 for your answer.